# Find most frequent observation in group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

DataFrame:

```
B = pd.DataFrame({'b':['II','II','II','II','II','I','I','I'],
                  'MOST_FREQUENT':['1', '2', '2', '1', '1','1','2','2']})
```

I need to get the most frequent value in a column `MOST_FREQUENT` for each group:

```
pd.DataFrame({'b':['I','II'],
                      'MOST_FREQUENT':['2','1']})
```

The only clue i found - `mode()`, but is not applieble to `DataFrameGroupBy`

**EDIT: I need a solution, which satisfies the pandas' `.agg()` function**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply`:

```
print (B.groupby('b')['MOST_FREQUENT'].apply(lambda x: x.mode())
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index())
    b MOST_FREQUENT
0   I             2
1  II             1
```

Another solution is use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and return first `index` value, because `value_counts` sorts values:

```
print (B.groupby('b')['MOST_FREQUENT'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
        .reset_index())
    b MOST_FREQUENT
0   I             2
1  II             1
```

EDIT: You can use [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
print (B.groupby(['b']).agg(lambda x: Counter(x).most_common(1)[0][0]).reset_index())
    b MOST_FREQUENT
0   I             2
1  II             1
```

Comment: How can i make your `lambda` work in an `.agg()` function?

Comment: You can try `print (B.groupby('b').agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
       ))`

Comment: But now I am offline, only on phone, so cannot test.

Comment: Unfortunatly, still not. It says: `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`

Comment: Ceck edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to squeeze a little more performance out of pandas, we can use `groupby` with size to get the counts. then use `idxmax` to find the index values of the largest sub-groups.  These indices will be the values we're looking for.

```
s = B.groupby(['MOST_FREQUENT', 'b']).size()
pd.DataFrame(
    s.groupby(level='b').idxmax().values.tolist(),
    columns=s.index.names
)

  MOST_FREQUENT   b
0             2   I
1             1  II
```

---

***naive timing***

[image]

Comment: How can i use it in `.agg()` function? Why do you group by both columns?